# GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync throws "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I really don't get why I am getting this exception: "The system cannot find the file specified".

Please check the code below. I was able to get file `test3` but unable to get `test2`. I am pretty sure they are under the same folder. And I also wasn't able to read other files under the `ms-appx` path except for the png files under the Assets folder.

Can somebody please help? This is the [link](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Helpers/VoiceAssistantHelper.cs) to my code and this is the link to the [Assets folder](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/tree/master/SMPlayer/Assets).

```
  var test3 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/folder.png"));
  var test2 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/zh.grxml"));
```

Comment: I can nearly guarantee you your file is not set to output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project file you will see this

```
<Content Include="Assets\folder.png" />
<None Include="Assets\zh.grxml" />
```

Make `zh.grxml` copy to the output directory (one way or another) and you will have consistent results

**Example**

```
<Content Include="Assets\zh.grxml" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering the question and please forgive my silliness, which project file do you mean? I searched `Include` and `Content` but counldn't get any result. And is there document related to what you said `output` stuff? Microsoft doesn't explain anything on this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefromapplicationuriasync?view=winrt-22000 .

Comment: @SeakyLone https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/SMPlayer.csproj